# Is there a JSON schema validator provided by Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: json, database, validation, plsql, schema

I could find a XML validator implmented by PL/SQL using XML schema. Is there a similar way to validate JSON using a JSON schema in PL/SQL?

XML validator- https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/validate-xml-against-xml-schema-xsd

Answer (score 1):

You can create a JSON table with a JSON constrained column, and use that.

```
CREATE TABLE my_json_table (
  id RAW(16) NOT NULL,
  json_data CLOB,
  CONSTRAINT myjson_headers_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT myjson_json_chk CHECK (json_data IS JSON)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_json_valid (p_json IN CLOB)
RETURN BOOLEAN IS
  e_invalid EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (e_invalid, -1000);
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO my_json_table (id, json_data)
    VALUES (SYS_GUID(), p_json);

    ROLLBACK;

    RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN e_invalid THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
END;
```

Comment: But this will only check if it is a JSON format or not right? I want to validate it against a schema

Comment: Yes, but I think the only way you can do that is to actually call the service. Someone will correct me if that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a JSON schema validator in Oracle.

But you can think of a workaround.
You can build the schema as in XML, parse your JSON to XML and then validate the XML against your schema.

Below you can find how to parse a JSON to XML:

```
DECLARE
  l_json VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_xml  XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
  l_json := '[
               {"department_number":10,"department_name":"ACCOUNTING"},
               {"department_number":20,"department_name":"RESEARCH"}
             ]';

  l_xml := APEX_JSON.to_xmltype(l_json );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_xml.getClobVal());
END;
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json>
    <row>
        <department_number>10</department_number>
        <department_name>ACCOUNTING</department_name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <department_number>20</department_number>
        <department_name>RESEARCH</department_name>
    </row>
</json>
```

Otherwise you have to go with service validation.